# How to subtract dates from eachother (python)

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
    for dictionary in ministers:
        if(math.floor((datetime.date.today() - dictionary[3]).days/365.25) <50):
            print(dictionary[1], dictionary[2], math.floor((datetime.datetime.today() - dictionary[3]).days/365.25))
```

I am supposed to take today's date and subtract from that a date given in a list of dictionaries. Here is that list of dictionaries:

```
 ministers = [{1: "Alexander", 2: "De Croo", 3: "3-11-1975", 4: "Vilvoorde", 5: "Open Vld"},
             {1: "Sophie", 2: "Wilmès", 3: "15-01-1975", 4: "Elsene", 5: "MR"},
             {1: "Frank", 2: "Vandenbroucke", 3: "21-10-1955", 4: "Leuven", 5: "sp.a"},
             {1: "Petra", 2: "De Sutter", 3: "10-6-1963", 4: "Oudenaarde", 5: "groen"},
             {1: "Sammy", 2: "Mahdi", 3: "21-9-1988", 4: "Elsene", 5: "CD&V"},
             {1: "Zakia", 2: "Khattabi", 3: "15-1-1976", 4: "Sint-Joost-ten-Node", 5: "Ecolo"},
             {1: "Ludivine", 2: "Dedonder", 3: "17-3-1977", 4: "Doornik", 5: "PS"},
             {1: "Karine", 2: "Lalieux", 3: "4-5-1964", 4: "Anderlecht", 5: "PS"},]
```

If the resulted number is smaller than 50 then I am supposed to indicate that. But it is impossible to subtract 2 dates from each other like this, I'm aware of that but I can't find any fix or way around this. I'm still very new to python and programming in general.

This is the resulting error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'str'**

I have tried converting the dates into an int or float, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: You're [talking](https://xyproblem.info/) about your attempted solution rather than talking about the actual problem. Is it your goal to find out which ministers are younger than 50 years old?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is saying, your subtraction does not work because you are trying to subtract a string from a date, and python does not know how to do it.

The solution is to subtract date from a date, like in this example:

```py
date_1 = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
date_2 = datetime.date(2018, 11, 10)

print(date_2 - date_1)

# prints -52 days, 0:00:00
```

Now to get there, you will need to convert the strings such as "15-1-1975" to dates. For this use the following function:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("15-1-1976", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approximate solution to your problem:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()

ministers = [
     {1: "Alexander", 2: "De Croo", 3: "3-11-1975", 4: "Vilvoorde", 5: "Open Vld"},
     {1: "Sophie", 2: "Wilmès", 3: "15-01-1975", 4: "Elsene", 5: "MR"},
     {1: "Frank", 2: "Vandenbroucke", 3: "21-10-1955", 4: "Leuven", 5: "sp.a"},
     {1: "Petra", 2: "De Sutter", 3: "10-6-1963", 4: "Oudenaarde", 5: "groen"},
     {1: "Sammy", 2: "Mahdi", 3: "21-9-1988", 4: "Elsene", 5: "CD&V"},
     {1: "Zakia", 2: "Khattabi", 3: "15-1-1976", 4: "Sint-Joost-ten-Node", 5: "Ecolo"},
     {1: "Ludivine", 2: "Dedonder", 3: "17-3-1977", 4: "Doornik", 5: "PS"},
     {1: "Karine", 2: "Lalieux", 3: "4-5-1964", 4: "Anderlecht", 5: "PS"}
]

for minister in ministers:
    dob = datetime.strptime(minister[3], '%d-%m-%Y')
    if today - dob < timedelta(days=18250):
        print(f"Minister {minister[1]} is younger than 50")
```